# Set context in Dialogflow through Promise Request

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, request-promise

I am having a problem with the contexts of dialogflow, when trying to change them through fulfillment. 
When I want to add (or clear, by setting lifespanCount to -1) a context I generally use this code:

```
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
/*Irrelevant Code Here*/
var context=agent.session+"/contexts/contextName";
agent.setContext({
      "name":context,
      "lifespanCount": 1            
});
```

If I use this snippet, the contexts can be successfully manipulated. However, I am now trying to use this snippet when sending a **request-promise** and, based on the response of that request, I want to have different outputContexts. For some reason, this action doesn't have any results, I cannot clear the contexts or create one, as these don't appear on the Firebase logs when I print *JSON.stringify(request.body)*.

```
return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    const request = require('request-promise-native');
    const options = {  
    uri: 'link',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'api-token': 'token'
    },
    body: {
        someData:"someData",
    },
    json: true
    };
    request(options)
        .then(function (body) {
        if (body.status===0)
            agent.add("Option 1");
        else {
            var sessionIdArray=agent.session.split("/");
            var sessionId=sessionIdArray[sessionIdArray.length-1];      
            var context=agent.session+"/contexts/contextName";
            agent.setContext({
                "name":context,
                "lifespanCount": 1            
                });
            agent.add("type something");
            }
        resolve();
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // POST failed...
        agent.add("An error happened during your last call.");
        console.log(err.stack);
        resolve();
    });
});
```

It's like the promise-request prevents the agent to set the context. Does anyone know how to make this work? Thanks in advance!